# Taxcloud.net integration for Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

We have a lot of exemptions, re-seller and agriculture, as well as states to report. this tool calculates and accepts the customers exemptions. We are looking at making a plugin but wanted to see if it has already been done.

The service is no or low cost and does the filing for a good number of states. So this is a great alternative to other sales tax services.

Answer (score 2):

As of Sept. 27 2016, I'm not aware of any existing taxcloud.net integrations with Craft Commerce and I'm not seeing any on https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/ as well.